# Format currency amount using Indian numeral separator in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I have an query which is giving me total amount like 100000.0000 and I want to show this like **100000** has to be displayed as Rs. **1,00,000.00**

Here is my query:

```
String sql = " select distinct round(sum(netamount)) as amount from syncbill where cancelled<>'Y' and year(curdate())=year(billdate)";
ResultSet resultSetYtd = statement.executeQuery(YtdQuery);
while (resultSetYtd.next()) {
  String AmountYtd = resultSetYtd.getString("amount");
  system.out.println(AmountYtd);

}
```

Can I achieve this with query only?

Comment: `FORMAT()` should be your friend

Comment: You should do this in your program logic and not in SQL

Comment: @juergend actually i am using java  but don't know how to do there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for Indian numeral separators (lakhs, crores). We can use [`Format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function, with third parameter set to [`en_IN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html) (English - India) locale. Second parameter is set to 2 for specifying 2 decimal places after decimal point `.`. Finally, the CONCAT('Rs. ') adds the currency to the result.

```
select CONCAT('Rs. ', FORMAT(sum(netamount), 2, 'en_IN')) 
from syncbill
```

**Demo**

```
select format(100000,2,'en_IN');

| format(100000,2,'en_IN') |
| ------------------------ |
| 1,00,000.00              |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qogKeApgPhwNy8p4A4Nf7i/1)

---

**Edit:** However, as discussed further in comments, your MySQL server version is significantly old (5.1) and it does not support `Format()` function with Locale parameter. Check 5.1 documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.1/functions.html#function_format).

Comment: hey it is giving some wrong results  like for  27227004 it shows 27,227,004 but actually it should show 2,72,27,004.. so any suggestion please

Comment: @manishthakur maybe you don't have locale support installed/configured? Using the DB Fiddle provided in the answer [with "27227004"](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qogKeApgPhwNy8p4A4Nf7i/2) it correctly returns `2,72,27,004.00`

Comment: @JariKeinänen yupp i am using mysql5 and this format function is not there ..can you helpme out that how colud i achieve that using java?

Comment: its 5.1 and i got to know that its not gonna work in 5.1

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya its not the idian format  indian format for27227004  will be 2,72,27,004

Comment: @manishthakur ohh I missed that part. Let me find something else then.

Comment: same result..hey i have found the solution no need to worry now..thanx for your time and advice :)

Comment: @manishthakur what are you using now, which has solved your problem.

Comment: actually i am rendring the data using javascript so i did that using javascript

Comment: @manishthakur I am also trying to create a user-defined function in MySQL itself. Will post it once ready.

Answer (score 1):

The changelog for **5.5.0** says

> The [FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function now supports an optional third parameter that enables a locale to be specified to be used for the result number's decimal point, thousands separator, and grouping between separators. Permissible locale values are the same as the legal values for the [lc_time_names](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lc_time_names) system variable (see [MySQL Server Locale Support](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/locale-support.html)). For example, the result from [FORMAT(1234567.89,2,'de_DE')](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format) is 1.234.567,89. If no locale is specified, the default is 'en_US'.

So, it should be working if you have 5.5 or later.  If you are still having troubles, provide further details.

(Caveat:  Those links will break when 5.5 hits EOL.  Edit the links to say 5.6; those may work.)